# Multiple form textfield

Tags: php, html

How can I get only values of the form fields that have marked checkbox?

Form:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">

<input type="text" name="textfield[]"  value="textf 1"/>
<textarea name="textarea[]" cols="45" rows="5">some text 1</textarea>
<input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="checkb 1" />

<input type="text" name="textfield[]"  value="textf 2" />
<textarea name="textarea[]" cols="45" rows="5">some text 2</textarea>
<input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="checkb 2" />

<input type="text" name="textfield[]"   value="textf 3"/>
<textarea name="textarea[]" cols="45" rows="5">some text 3</textarea>
<input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="checkb 3" />

</form>
```

I want to get form field values for specific textfield and textarea. For example if I mark the first and last checkbox in this example. How can I do that using PHP?

Then result should be:

```
textf 1
some text 1
checkb 1

textf 3
some text 3
checkb 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your checkboxes and textareas set indexes so you know easily which checkbox corresponds to what form.

```
<input type="text" name="textfield[0]"  value="textf 1"/>
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea[0]" cols="45" rows="5">some text 1</textarea>
<input name="check[0]" type="checkbox" value="checkb 1" />

<input type="text" name="textfield[1]"  value="textf 2" />
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea[1]" cols="45" rows="5">some text 2</textarea>
<input name="check[1]" type="checkbox" value="checkb 2" />
```

Then you can quickly check whether a specific checkbox is set, and do something with the associated textarea.

```
foreach ($_POST['textfield'] as $idx => $value) {
  echo $_POST['textfield'][$idx] . "<br />";
  echo $_POST['textarea'][$idx] . "<br />";
}
```

That will only print the textareas that have checked textfields, since those that weren't checked aren't in $_POST.